# Handling binary image or files with NodeJS/ExpressJS through POST request

Tags: node.js, express

I would like to know if there is a way to handle a POST request containing just a file, **no form**, just a binary sent as body of the request.

```js
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const logger = require('morgan');

// Settings
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000)

// Middlewares
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.headers);
    
    let data = ''
    
    req.on('data', chunk => {
        data += chunk;
    })

    req.on('end', () => {
        fs.writeFileSync('img.jpg', data)
    })
    
    res.send('ok');
})

app.listen(app.get('port'), console.log(`Listening on any ${app.get('port')}`));
```

I've tried to make this request: (sorry for external link, I just created the account)

[**POSTMAN**, using *binary* option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F480r.png)

Headers:

```js
{
  'user-agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.26.5',
  accept: '*/*',
  'postman-token': 'aca04fab-a66d-439a-962f-87ede2b8bb98', 
  host: 'localhost:3000',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'content-length': '73989'
}
```

and is not working, `img.jpg` is just corrupt.

***UPDATE: (thanks to [eol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3761628/eol) for his help)***

This is how code works now, with `express.raw` built-in middleware:

```js
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.raw({type: '*/*'}));

app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
    fs.writeFileSync('img.jpg', req.body);
    res.send('ok');
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in [bodyparser](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html#bodyparserrawoptions) should be able to do this out of the box as far as I know. Try setting it up with:

```
app.use(express.raw({type: 'application/octet-stream'}))
```

Inside your handler `req.body` should then hold a buffer of the content:

```
app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
  // req.body should hold the bindary-data as a buffer
});
```

Comment: It didn't work with ```octet-stream``` MIME type. I used ```{type: '*/*`}``` instead and did validation from request headers, thank you.

Comment: If the `Content-Type` is set as `application/octet-stream` then how should the client send the file type for example, JPEG or PNG image or PDF file? A custom header perhaps? Or is there an implicit way that the server can reliably "guess" the file type from the binary data alone?